# MySQL encoding only works on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, encoding, character-encoding

I have a PHP script which saves some data into a MySQL db using PDO.

On my Mac, I am using MAMP which is running PHP 7.1 and MySQL 5.6.35.
On my VPS, I am using apache2 which is running PHP 7.0 and MySQL 5.7.

I imported the exact database sql file to my remote server as I have locally, however I am facing some problems with encoding.

Locally, everything gets saved nicely into the database. On my remote however, a lot of non-latin characters show up as random symbols. As mentioned above, the remote database uses the same encoding as the local database. I am guessing it is a problem on the PHP side.

**EDIT:** I am trying to save some Hungarian text if that helps.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Run `SHOW TABLE STATUS` command on both databases to see what is the table collation.

Comment: They match exactly. utfmb_unicode_ci

Comment: Run `SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA 
WHERE schema_name = "schemaname";` to see the schema charset

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I checked it and the remote one was latin1. I created a new database with utf-8, but still no success...

Comment: See "Best Practice" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Setting it to utf-8mb4 solved it for me, thanks! It's weird though because on localhost, it works even with utf-8.